# Power Automate Flow, translate comma separated string to choices in Sharepoint

Tags: arrays, json

I have a Sharepoint list with multiple columns, and I want my Choice columns to not just be represented as text (values separated by a comma e.g. a field in that choice column looks like this: ABC, DEF, GHI... and so on) but I want the text to become individual choices within that column. This means that I want to enable the option to filter on 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI' and so on.

So my question is; how to I take my comma-separated data and transform it into individual choices with the help of Power Automate?